# How to convert Text to Date and time in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the value `2018-06-20  18:41:29` in Excel and want to convert it to `6/20/2018  6:41:29 PM` in Excel. I have performed the following steps but I am not there yet:

**step 1:** =datetime(2018-06-20 18:41:29) on a new cell. It becomes the values of 43271.

**step 2:** =TEX(cell above, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM").

What should I have done to get `6/20/2018  6:41:29 PM` in Excel?

Comment: The formula should start with =Text( but that returns a text string not a date. What you could try is formatting the date with a custom format. Check this: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/11/change-date-format-excel/

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Paste the value from before your step 1 (the *2018-06-20 18:41:29*) into a cell, use Cells->Format->Format Cells from the ribbon, and choose whatever date format you'd like (or modify one of them to suit your needs as a custom format). No multiple steps or functions involved. From code, set the cell's `NumberFormat` to the same format string you'd use in the Format Cells dialog. In either case, the format you're looking for would be `m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM`.

Comment: (continued) I just did this: 1) Copy the exact value from between the () in your step 1. 2) Paste it into cell A1 in Excel. 3) Use Cells->Format->Format Cells, set the format to 'm/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM`, and clicked OK. The value in the cell changed from `2018-06-20 18:41:29` to `6/20/2018 6:41:29 PM`.

Answer (score 0):

By formula, your ***Step 2*** has a typo.
`=TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")`
This formula works.

Or try by formatting.
Right click the cell
In the Context menu choose Format Cells...
On the Number Tab, click `Custom` on the left
Under Type: Change from `YYYY-MM-DD H:MM` to `m/d/yyyy H:MM AM/PM` or just make sure that `m/d/yyyy H:MM AM/PM` is there

Comment: Thanks every for the help!

Comment: Sure, can you upvote the answer that helped for others that may read your question?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all dates are stored as numbers in excel. If there is a time component, it gets stored as numeric with decimals. The following steps can be followed ( from ablebits.com) . There is a picture in the site to follow along with the steps.

How to change date format in Excel
In Microsoft Excel, dates can be displayed in a variety of ways. When it comes to changing date format of a given cell or range of cells, the easiest way is to open the Format Cells dialog and choose one of the predefined formats.

Select the dates whose format your want to change, or empty cells where you want to insert dates.
Press Ctrl+1 to open the Format Cells dialog. Alternatively, you can right click the selected cells and choose Format Cells… from the context menu.
In the Format Cells window, switch to the Number tab, and select Date in the Category list.
Under Type, pick a desired date format. Once you do this, the Sample box will display the format preview with the first date in your selected data.
Changing the date format in Excel
If you are happy for the preview, click the OK button to save the format change and close the window.
If the date format is not changing in your Excel sheet, most likely your dates are formatted as text and you have to convert them to the date format first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to format your cell directly, as suggested, because it already contains text.

The way to achieve your objective is to put a new formula into an adjacent cell.
If the text you have is in cell `A1`, then place a formula in cell `B1` saying:

```
=DATEVALUE(A1) +  TIMEVALUE(A1)
```

This will give you the numerical value that you can format easily, as suggested above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. I've made minor adjustments to the formatting of your post. Please review both to make sure that they're consistent with your expectation and, if so, to apply similar formatting to your future posts.